# How can I make my responsive bootstrap image perfectly round?

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my image perfectly round and responsive. I'm using Bootstrap 4's class `rounded-circle` with `img-fluid` but the image is oval, not circle. The images will be uploaded by users, so they won't be (always) squared.

```css
.nh-service-card img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 nh-service-card-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="Reebit" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="85" height="85">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know the size of each image that is being uploaded?

Comment: @Dominik No. Each user can upload an image of any size.

Comment: My question is: Does your backend give you the individual size of each image that is being uploaded? Because that would help a lot ;)

Comment: @Dominik. I'm not sure, I would have to ask my dev team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. `object-fit` only works if you define an explicit height for the replaced element
2. Your class names are incorrect: in your markup you have `nh-service-card-img` but in your selector you have `nh-service-card`

My solution hinges on the requirement that you can modify the DOM to add an additional wrapper `<div>` around the image.

## Solution 1: `aspect-ratio: 1`

The most modern way to do this is to simply set `aspect-ratio: 1` on the wrapping element. The [`aspect-ratio` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) is [relatively well-supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio), especially among modern evergreen browsers.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.nh-service-card-img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 nh-service-card-img">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="Reebit" class="rounded-circle" width="85" height="85">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Solution 2: `padding-bottom: 100%` to force square aspect ratio

Alternatively, if you want to support older browsers, use the `padding-bottom` trick:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.nh-service-card-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 nh-service-card-img">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png" alt="Reebit" class="rounded-circle" width="85" height="85">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```